# Kogito cloud-events extensions in process instance context

Tags: kogito

I'm trying to implement a small project on Kogito.
I use kogito-addons-quarkus-messaging + kafka + cloud events.

The question is:
How to get data written in cloud-events extensions in the context of a process instance?

I send a message to the service's incoming channel:

headers:

```
ce_id: 6dfde9b9-886e-4674-9936-1c6e2bfcd5dd, ce_kogitobusinesskey: asdasd, ce_source: https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-java/tree/main/examples/kafka, ce_specversion: 1.0, ce_test: rest, ce_type: GetAccountList
```

payload:

```
{
   "a": "b"
}
```

the process instance starts, the payload is written to a variable, the business key is pulled up. Everything is fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csx27.png)

Next, a service task is called, in which I log various data by context, but I can’t find the extension from the **ce_test** header anywhere

```
    public void showAll (KogitoProcessContext context) {
        System.out.println("headers: " + context.getHeaders());
        System.out.println("contextData: " + context.getContextData());
        if (!context.getContextData().isEmpty()) {
            context.getContextData().forEach((s, o) -> {
                System.out.println("CD name: " + s + " val: " + o);
            });
        }
        System.out.println("vars: " + context.getProcessInstance().getVariables());
        System.out.println("process meta: " + context.getProcessInstance().getProcess().getMetaData());
        System.out.println("node meta: " + context.getNodeInstance().getNode().getMetaData());
        System.out.println("PI_headers: " + context.getProcessInstance().getHeaders());
        System.out.println("events: " + Arrays.toString(context.getProcessInstance().getEventTypes()));
    }
```

Is it possible to interact with the **ce_test: rest** extension from event in bpmn or is it ignored and not written anywhere?

Comment: Cloud event attributes are currently not considered to be headers. This is a good candidate for feature request. Can you please file a Kogito JIRA with subject "Cloud event attributes should be avaiable as headers in kogitoprocesscontext"

Comment: thanks for reply https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-9281